# dnndev.me giving "This site can’t be reached. dnndev.me refused to connect." error

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I am a C# developer and have installed DNN locally multiple times and up to a couple of weeks ago everything was working fine. Earlier this week I needed to debug a module of ours, something I've done many times before, and when I tried to bring up the dnndev.me site I got the error "This site can't be reached...dnndev.me refused to connect".

Unfortunately I don't know what may have changed in my laptop over the last couple of weeks that might be causing this. Here's what I've tried so far with no success:

- deleted the dnndev.me website located in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\
- uninstalled/re-installed IIS to include deleting the inetpub folder
- after DNN uninstall unzipped the dnn 8.0.4.226 install zip file into
  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnndev.me folder
- created dnndev.me website which uses dnndev.me app pool
- verified permissions on dnndev.me folder includes full control for dnndev.me account
- deleted/recreated dnndev.me database and set up account with dbowner
  permissions to the dnndev.me database for the login I created
- cleared the browser cache
- flushed dns
- ipconfig/release and renew
- tried incognito
- tried chrome/edge/firefox
- verified the host file is empty
- verified my Windows Feature on/off are correct
- verified my windows defender firewall is Off
- verified there's no proxy being used
- verified when I ping dnndev.me I get the expected 127.0.0.1 IP
- verified when I tracert to dnndev.me it's only going to my local
  laptop url
- verified the IIS "Default Web Site" comes up fine

At this point I should be able to browse to dnndev.me and get the DNN setup screen but instead I get the error I mentioned.

I've run out of options and cannot find anything online that is similar.  Does anyone have any suggested on what I can try before I have to replace this laptop?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Ok...I won't say I figured it out but I was able to bring the DNN Setup page up.  Here's what I did.

I noticed/remembered that the default website that IIS installs which it names "Default Web Site" is installed in the root "wwwroot" folder and that it worked fine. Yet the DNN sites created under it do not.

So I then tried creating a simple 1 page website in a "testsite" folder in wwwroot and it also did not work. Same error.

So on a whim I copied all the files from the dnndev.me folder into the wwwroot folder and gave permissions to the IIS_IUSRS account and I was able to bring up the DNN Setup page by browsing the "Default Web Site" or localhost!?

So it seems to be a permissions issue? Or IIS issue? But one I've never heard of.

What is even stranger is that I then created a dnndev.me web site with the dnndev.me app pool, gave the folder the dnndev.me app pool permissions etc. and pointed it to the root wwwroot folder...but if I browse to it using the dnndev.me URL it does not come up but gives me the "This site can’t be reached dnndev.me refused to connect."!!!???

But if I browse to it using "localhost" or click the browse link for the default website the dnn setup page comes up?!

So to put it mildly I have no idea what is going on...I was going to mark my question as answered with this information but I realized that I do not know why it works in wwwroot but not in the dnndev.me subfolder or any subfolder. Nor is it a viable solution.

I'm hoping that with this additional information someone might recognize what is going on?

Comment: Do you get other error messages besides this error message? Are there any relevant error messages in the console or in Event Vierer?

Comment: @samwu No there's no other messages that I can find. I've looked in the event viewer and there are no events that could be related to this issue.  I've also looked at the IIS logs and what is interesting is that there is no record of IIS receiving the DNNDEV.ME request. 

This would seem more and more like there's a firewall blocking it but the windows defender firewall is turned off and none of the other developers have the same issue.

Comment: You can try to use failed request tracing, then go to its log to check if the request was successful, if it is successful, then there will be a related error message, if not, then it should not be a problem with iis.

Comment: @samwu, thanks for the suggestion...I enabled it but it doesn't create a log.  I assume that means the request is not making it to IIS?  Which would match what I see in the IIS logs which is there is no sign of a request to dnndev.me but I do see requests to the default website

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Any luck finding the problem with this?  I seem to have this problem, too.  Changing permissions on the folder for my app-pool did nothing.  In my case, the default DNN installer webpages do come up, but my site does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had (or have) this very often... The reason is that when you open the project in Visual Studio, a virtual directory and an application are created for your project in IIS. Go to IIS Manger, delete these two from your web site, and it should work again...

Comment: I'm familiar with that issue and I have verified that neither the DesktopModules nor any other folders is marked with the little arrow denoting a virtual drive and none of them are  set as applications either.

Comment: I had these, but removed them.  Still connection is refused.